# Is There Any Downside to Using An Air Impact Driver to Drive Screws?

Tags: drill

I was interested in using an air impact driver that I had for automotive work and using it to drive screws in my shop. Is there any downside to using an impact driver this way? I know that these types of impact drivers have more torque than a standard drill. The conversion kit looks like this: [https://www.amazon.com/Neiko-20754A-Change-Convert-Impact/dp/B0051AE85W/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1495757695&sr=8-1&keywords=Impact+Wrench+Drill+Chuck](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0051AE85W)

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your idea as long as you remember that the air impact will drive the screws very quickly and with a lot of torque.

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about two very different machines.

- an air impact wrench used in shops on bolts typically 3/8" and larger, that would be too tough to work with a ratchet or breaker bar. The classic example is a tire shop removing lug nuts.
- An electric drill.  It looks, walks and quacks like an electric drill.  Except it's jazzed up with a geardown for driving screws (a "drill-driver"), and a centrifugal impact feature to give it a bit more "kick" to help you cam out screws better ("impact drill-driver").

The tool you linked is made for electric drill-drivers.

For your air impact wrench, the tool you're looking to break is called a **bit holder**. It's a much simpler affair. It snaps onto a common 1/4, 3/8 or 1/2 square drive meant for sockets, and gives you a standard 1/4” hex drive that takes Philips, Torx, Robertson etc. bits that you normally use for deck and drywall screws. It has a magnet or clip to keep the bit in place.

I prefer using one with a speed wrench.

Comment: I've found that bit holders are hard to find on the web due to naming conventions. I use the Milwaukee, though other manufacturers have similar products. Google "Milwaukee Shockwave™ 1/4 In. Hex Adapter Sq 3/8 In. ‑ 48‑03‑4405" Buy good quality impact rated bits. Be prepared to break a few screws initially, as the torque on the air tool will be substantial.